# Get the complete username a new username

Tags: winapi

When using [NetUserAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370649(VS.85).aspx) the user will be created on the local computer or as a domain account depending the role of the server where you used this function.

I want to retrieve the complete username (LOCALCOMPUTER\USERNAME or DOMAIN\USERNAME) to use it remotely.

Is there a function to do this?

Comment: Which language? Tag appropriately

Comment: The language not matters I'm using C++ but I'm searching the correct function from Windows API.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: I haven't checked the solution.
You may call NetGetJoinInformation to know if the machine belongs to a domain and NetServerGetInfo if the code is running on a DC.
After those test you may get the machine name (GetComputerName) and domain name (NetWkstaGetInfo) and whatever you need.

Be careful if you are doing this on a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I'm missing something, but can't you use [`GetUserNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pass in the desired [`EXTENDEND_NAME_FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms902883.aspx)? I believe `NameSamCompatible` should be the format you desire.

You'll get back either `MachineName\UserName` or `DomainName\UserName`